# File upload is not working properly in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, file-upload

I am uploading a file from file upload control in asp.net. On that page there is a checkbox. User have to accept condition before he can upload the file. I am checking on code behind file that if the checkbox is not checked that show an alert message but the problem is that before calling that function the file is going to buffer whole on server and then the function is going called. But i want to to check that condition before temporary uploading of that file.

Below is my code that I am working with-

```
protected void btn_Upload_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!chkBx_1.Checked )
        {
            dataclass.Message("Please accept all terms before uploading", this);
            return;

        }
        else
        {
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                FileUpload1.SaveAs("path");
            }

        }        
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use some client side technology (javascript, silverlight, etc..) to check the checkbox first before submitting your form to the server.

If you want to be sure, you can recheck the checkbox on the serverside then.

Comment: can you please post me the exact jquery to do so. I am very new to sciprting languages

Comment: Cleverer people than me have answered this already : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery

Comment: You can show the FileUpload control only when the CheckBox is checked. This can be don via Javascript-JQuery or using some Ajax and Async Postback (in this case don't foget to use AsyncFileUpload)

Comment: but the problem is this that i have used many server side validation. If i use javascript or jquery then those validations get conflicts

Answer (score 1):

It will be much easier for you to validate the `checkbox` in client side before continue.
Have look at this article about [Related checkbox validation with JQuery](http://daveshuck.com/2008/07/16/related-checkbox-validation-with-jquery/). Also within the `click` function you can use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

eg.

```
<input id="chbTest" cssClass="clChb" value="1" type="checkbox">
<script language="javascript">
(document).ready(function(){
$("#btnUpload").click(function(event){

    if ($(".clChb").attr("checked") == false){
            event.preventDefault();
            alert('Please accept all terms before uploading ');
    }

});

});
</script>
```

Also if you are not much familiar, you can have a look at this article about [Using jQuery with ASP.NET](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=231)  which shows you how to include necessary script libraries.

Comment: can you please post me the exact jquery to do so. I am very new to sciprting languages

Answer (score 1):

Try to validate this checkbox with toolbox validator "RequiredFieldValidator".